# Android: Change YouTube link name in WebView

Tags: android, string, url, youtube, android-webview

I am getting a string from a RSS Feed which sometimes includes a link to a YouTube video. I was already able to parse the URL out of the string.

I want that inside the WebView the URL is replaced by "Link to video" but on a click on this link it should use the YouTube link.

At the moment I replace the string but on click on this string, the new string is forwarded and not the YouTube URL.

My code:

```
String description = fFeed.getItem(fPos).getDescription();

    // get all links from the description string
    ArrayList<String> links_in_string = retrieveLinks(description);
    Log.d("debug", "All Links: " + links_in_string.toString());

    // search for YouTube links
    ArrayList<String> resList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String searchString = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=";

    for (String curVal : links_in_string) {
        if (curVal.contains(searchString)) {
            resList.add(curVal);
        }
    }
    Log.d("debug", "YouTube Links: " + resList.toString());

    // convert to single YouTube URL strings and replace
    // them in the description string
    Object[] mStringArray = resList.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length; i++) {
        Log.d("string is", (String) mStringArray[i]);
        description = description.replace((String) mStringArray[i],
                "Link zum Video");
    }


/**
 * Retrieve all the links from the description string
 * of the RSS Feed
 */
private ArrayList<String> retrieveLinks(String text) {
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();

    String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        String urlStr = m.group();
        if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")")) {
            urlStr = urlStr.substring(1, urlStr.length() - 1);
        }
        links.add(urlStr);
    }
    return links;
}
```

**Update**

I have to search for every second time the url appears in the string. I tried it this way but now it does not replace the URLs

```
// convert to single YouTube URL strings and replace
        // them in the description string
        Object[] mStringArray = resList.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length; i++) {

            //replace every second URL by "Link zum Video"
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile((String) mStringArray[i]);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(description);
            int count = 0;
            while (m.find()) {
                if (count++ % 2 != 0) {
                    m.appendReplacement(sb, "Link zum Video");
                }
            }
            m.appendTail(sb);
            description = sb.toString();

            Log.d("debug", "Description with replaced link: " + description);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using RegEx:

```
String pattern = "(<a href=\".*?\">).*?(</a>)";
description = description.replaceAll(pattern, "$1Link zum Video$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not test it, but maybe using a anchor tag will work:

```
description = description.replace((String) mStringArray[i],
                "<a href=\""+(String) mStringArray[i]+"\">Link zum Video</a>");
```

Comment: Seems not to work. If I implement it the output looks like this: `Link zum Video">Link zum Video">Link zum Video">Link zum Video">` and so on. Every third one is a link, but directs not to the correct website.

Comment: I tried this code:  `description = description.replace((String) mStringArray[i],
     Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+(String) mStringArray[i]+"\">Link zum Video</a>")); `. Now only "Link zum Video" is shown but it also directs to this string as website. Any other idea?

Comment: You store the youtube link in mStringArray? If that true, what its value at that time?

Comment: The value is for example `"01-15 20:10:04.579: D/string is(6700): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urgILLOZokg
"`

Comment: Okay now I have more information for you. The string looks like this from the RSS feed:  `<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5drSYII5mFY">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5drSYII5mFY</a> `. So if I replace the URL I replace it at both positions. It then looks like this: `<a href="Link zum Video">Link zum Video</a> ` So I need to replace the string only every second time it occurs in the RSS feed. I added my function to search for every second string but now it doesn't replace it. You can see it in my original post.

Comment: you can try a trick, that we will replace a string "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v‌​=5drSYII5mFY</a>" with "Link zum video</a>" , so the anchor tag can work.